# Context Menu Missing 'Send To' Entries

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu, send-to

My installation of Windows 10 Pro x64 is missing entries in the 'Send To' context menu entry. In the past, I had programs list there, but now I have absolutely nothing listed at all. The only thing that is listed there is `DVD RW Drive (D:)`. I have tried following instructions provided [here](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-restore-missing-send-to-menuitem-in-file-and-folder-context-menus/), but they did not work. What happened to all my menu entries and how can I restore them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display the Run box by holding down the Windows (flag) key and pressing R

Clear the contents of the Run box if not empty and then enter the following text:

shell:sendto

Clicking OK should open the SendTo folder in File Explorer.

In the right window pane right-click the white-space and click New, click shortcut and then click Browse.

Select the desired target from the dialogue then click OK, click Next and finally click Finish.

I recommend adding a shortcut to notepad.  It is possible just by typing Notepad instead of clicking browse (and having to find the notepad executable file.  This is because notepad.exe is in the Windows folder which is included in the system Path environment variable value).

NOTE.
If all the items are there but don't show in the send to menu, right click each one and open their properties and uncheck hidden attributes box. Found that was the issue with mine.

Comment: In my case, some extension don't show (eg. script.ahk dont show, but script.exe does) any idea why?